# Cannot go through all the JSON Arrays and Objects

Tags: javascript, json

I need it to loop through an array of `tags` received as JSON from a server and show the name and the confidentiality for each tag. 
When I log the JSON to the console it shows a lot of information inside its `tags` property. But it is only adding one tag to the DOM.

```
.done(function(data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

    for (i = 0; i < obj.tags.length; i++){
      document.getElementById("tags-collection").innerHTML = '<a href="#!" class="collection-item"><span class="new badge red">'+ obj.tags[i].confidence +" %"+'</span>'+ obj.tags[i].name +'</a>';
    }
});
```

Comment: This code inside `for` loop doesn't have any sense. You are overwriting the innerHTML attr with every cycle.

Comment: Kind user is correct...  you are not adding a new element in each iteration of the for loop... you are overwriting it in each iteration

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're repeating this line

```
document.getElementById("tags-collection").innerHTML =
```

**in a loop**. Means that on every iteration you're changing, **modifying** the innerHTML of your `#tags-collection` element.

Instead try to **append** content like

```
insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", someContent)
```

like:

```
for (i = 0; i < obj.tags.length; i++){
  var someContent = '<a href="#!" class="collection-item"><span class="new badge red">'+ obj.tags[i].confidence +" %"+'</span>'+ obj.tags[i].name +'</a>';
  document.getElementById("tags-collection").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", someContent); 
}
```

A more performant way is to do **string contatenation** and insert only once:

```
var HTML = "";

for (i = 0; i < obj.tags.length; i++){
  HTML += '<a href="#!" class="collection-item"><span class="new badge red">'+ obj.tags[i].confidence +" %"+'</span>'+ obj.tags[i].name +'</a>';
}

// finally:
document.getElementById("tags-collection").innerHTML = HTML;
```

```js
const obj = {};
obj.tags = [
  {confidence:"12", name: "bar"},
  {confidence:"32", name: "foo"},
  {confidence:"66", name: "zoo"}
];

let HTML = "";

obj.tags.forEach((ob) => (
HTML += `<a href="#!" class="collection-item"><span class="new badge red">${ob.confidence}% </span> ${ob.name}</a><br>`
));

// finally:
document.getElementById("tags-collection").innerHTML = HTML;
```

```css
.red{color:red;}
```

```html
<div id="tags-collection"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

with this statement
      `document.getElementById("tags-collection").innerHTML = '<a href="#!" class="collection-item"><span class="new badge red">'+ obj.tags[i].confidence +" %"+'</span>'+ obj.tags[i].name +'</a>';` you are always overwriting the content.

Instead you can do the following:

```js
.done(function(data) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  var tagsCollection = document.getElementById("tags-collection")
  var currentContent = = tagsCollection.innerHTML

  for (i = 0; i < obj.tags.length; i++) {
    currentContent += '<a href="#!" class="collection-item"><span class="new badge red">' + obj.tags[i].confidence + " %" + '</span>' + obj.tags[i].name + '</a>';
  }

  tagsCollection.innerHTML = currentContent
});
```

Comment: Sorry to intrude, but why include a snippit if the code doesn't work?